# Spring Remoting with AMQP - Client is not seeing the beans exposed from Server

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, remoting

I'm trying to run example from http://www.baeldung.com/spring-remoting-amqp, even when I set up the connection to the dedicated vhost to my RabbitMQ broker, I can only send the request from client (I see it in RabbitMQ UI), but I never get the answer from the server.

The server seems to bean the service (the returning Impl class) with `getBeanDefinitionNames()`, but I definitly do not see those beans on the client side. I use annotations to set up beans, not the .xml file.

So the question is - why my client is not seeing the Server beans, I discover it more a less in following way:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

public GetResponse get(String id) {
  Service service = appContext.getBean(Service.class);
  System.out.println(service.ping());
  return new GetResponse();
}
```

The answer which I get on the level of webservice is:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-02-01T10:09:00.809Z",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.remoting.RemoteProxyFailureException",
  "message": "No reply received from 'toString' with arguments '[]' - perhaps a timeout in the template?",
"path": "/v3/app/r"
}
```

Service:

```
public interface Service extends Serializable{
  String ping();
}
```

Service Impl:

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

@Override
public String ping() {
  System.out.println("ponged");
  return "pong";
}

@Override
public String toString() {
  return "to string";
}
```

**EDITED + BOUNTY**

In the link you can find extracted modules which I want to connect together. I suppose that it is still about 'not seeing' the beans from one module in the second one.

The action can be trigerd with GET http://localhost:8081/v3/app/u The RabbitMQ settings has to be adjusted to your set-up.

https://bitbucket.org/herbatnic/springremotingexample/overview

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't set the routing key in your client, in amqpFactoryBean (and the one you set seems invalid):

https://bitbucket.org/herbatnic/springremotingexample/src/b1f08a5398889525a0b1a439b9bb4943f345ffd1/Mod1/src/main/java/simpleremoting/mod1/messaging/Caller.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Did you try to run their example?

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-remoting/remoting-amqp

Comment: Yes, I tried this example - let's say this is the exact example, but expanded to separate modules. The `amqpFactoryBean` I added, as I found it on SO some time ago (with or without it the it doesn't work). Without this line I get error: "Failed to instantiate [Service]: Specified class is an interface] with root cause  Specified class is an interface", with the line: "No reply received from 'ping' with arguments '[]' - perhaps a timeout in the template?"

Comment: having a bean for `amqpFactoryBean ` is fine (the example has one), but yours also has a routing key, I don't think you should set it, or use the correct one "remoting.binding" I guess.

Comment: I run the code with and without this param, as I wrote above I got two different errors. Anyway it didn't solve the issue that I can not run it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this question 3 years later.. trying to run the [Baeldung example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-remoting-amqp)!

I tried debugging the issue and as far as I can tell, something internal in the AMQP implementation of spring remoting is not using the correct Routing Key when sending the client message, meaning the payload arrives at the broker and is never put into the queue for processing, we then timeout after 5s (default) on the client.

I tried the other answer by Syl to remove the routingKey however it doesn't seem to allow us to create a binding without one, and even when creating a binding directly on the broker management page (without a routing key) it doesn't route the messages.

I have not managed to make the example work, however I found [a blog post](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/using-spring-amqp-to-realize-rpc-call.html) on fatalerrors.org that shows a custom implementation of the `AmqpProxyFactoryBean` and it has custom handling for the routing key, this one works.

I've create [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Fabricio20/bf5f10c132d04a0160b6359216bee04c) with the example that is working for me in case the blog post above goes under.

One other thing to note is that on the [Baeldung example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-remoting-amqp) they are using a `DirectExchange`, while here we are using a `TopicExchange`.